# Is there a simple way to test methods with mocha

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I'm having trouble to test methods of a js Class giving me the error:

> Cannot call a class as a function

The method I want to call is name()

The test code looks like this:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var chai = require('chai');
import {Player} from '../src/main'

var player = Player();

describe('player', function() {
    describe('#name()', function() {
        it('should return string', function() {
            assert.equal("string");
        });
    });
});
```

I'm obviously not able to instantiate the Player Class.
But how would you test the methods of this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is happening here `var player = Player();` because you are missing `new`.

Use `var player = new Player();`, and the error will be fixed you will be able to call methods on the instantiated Player like this: `player.name();`